# Bash scp several files password issue

Tags: bash, scp, remote-server

I am trying to copy several files from a remote server into local drive in Bash using scp.
Here's the part of the code

```
scp -r -q $USR@$IP:/home/file1.txt $PWD
scp -r -q $USR@$IP:/home/file2.txt $PWD
scp -r -q $USR@$IP:/root/file3.txt $PWD
```

However, the problem is that EVERY time that it wants to copy a file, it keeps asking for the password of the server, which is the same. I want it to ask only once and then copy all my files.

And please, do not suggest rsync nor making a key authentication file since I do not want to do that.
Are there any other ways...?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why do *you* not want to use the common solution that works for most SSH/SCP users?

Comment: how about : scp -r -q $USR@$IP:/home/file*.txt $PWD

Comment: @michael not all of them are in /home
if you see the third one is in /root

Comment: @NickC What do you mean?

Comment: @Matin SSH keys work for most users.  You state that "I do not want to do that".  Why not?  That is important information for the question.

Comment: @NickC Well I have researched about keys and yet I have not found anywhere that explains it well. (I am a beginner). So I figured I'd use what i'm using since the IP, USR, AND password are userdefined

Comment: @matin : you can create a passwordless key only for scp or list all files in one line with appropriate path. or write a expect script to handle password issues

Comment: @michael Can you please be more specific. I am a beginner. The Passwordless key for scp seems to be what I want. (Just remember that I cannot create nor modify anything inside the server.)

Comment: @matin : you need to read about ssh and public/private keys , do a search on google , this is a simple way of doing it : http://www.debian.org/devel/passwordlessssh

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expect` script or `sshpass`

`sshpass -p 'password' scp ...`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn scp ...
expect "password:"
send "ur_password"
```

An disadvantage is that your password is now in plaintext

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the script is for job and I don't think they have "expect" nor "sshpass" installed. Bash does not recognize expect nor spawn. And this script will be running on different places so I can't just install it on my linux.

Comment: spawn is an expect command, you can install/compile once (expect/sshpass) then copy the binary together with the script

Comment: Can you please rephrase?

Comment: you download expect/sshpass source, compile it in your own machine, then copy that binary along with the script to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that if you can scp files from the remote server, you can also ssh in and create a tarball of the remote files.

The -r flag is recursive, for copying entire directories but your listing distinct files in your command, so -r becomes superfluous.

Try this from the bash shell on the remote system:

```
$ mkdir /home/file_mover
$ cp /home/file1.txt /home/file_mover/
$ cp /home/file2.txt /home/file_mover/
$ cp /root/file3.txt /home/file_mover/

$ tar -cvf /home/myTarball.tar /home/file_mover/

$ scp -q $USR@$IP:/home/myTarball.tar  $PWD
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I cannot make files or folders in the remote server. I can only read

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this particular case, you can write...

```
scp -q $USR@$IP:/home/file[1-3].txt $PWD
```

Comment: Thank you but If you pay attention one of the files isn't in home. And not all the files are at the same path